# Power BI Slicer which select columns and not rows

Tags: powerbi, filtering, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have a problem with the Power BI slicer. I have a tables that looks something like this:

Table A:

| Date | Article A | Article B | Article C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29. Nov | $29.99 | $129.99 | $13.99 |
| 30. Nov | $32.99 | $132.99 | $14.99 |
| 1. Dec | $29.99 | $135.99 | $17.99 |
| 2. Dec | $27.99 | $137.99 | $20.99 |

Table B:

| Date | Article A | Article B | Article C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29. Nov | $32.99 | $135.99 | $11.99 |
| 30. Nov | $29.99 | $134.99 | $14.99 |
| 1. Dec | $27.99 | $132.99 | $20.00 |
| 2. Dec | $25.99 | $134.99 | $22.99 |

Now I would like to create a line chart that shows the date progression on the X-axis and the price on the Y-axis. This is working fine up to this point.

## **Now I want to insert two slicers.**

Slicer 1: Table selection (options here are: Table A, Table B)
Slicer 2: Product selection (options here are: Article A, Article B, Article C)

To do this I have already tried to create a relationship between the date columns.
If I create a slicer and select the articles the solution is for example: $29.99, $32.99,... but thats not that  i want.
If I transver the Table I have to select every single Date, so thats also not the solution.

How can i do this? Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you share a snip of your line chart in your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power Query, you should unpivot both tables on Article A to C columns, then add a custom column, then finally, Append the two tables.

| Date | Article | Table | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29/11/2023 | Article A | Table A | $ 29.99 |
| 29/11/2023 | Article A | Table B | $ 32.99 |
| 29/11/2023 | Article B | Table A | $ 129.99 |
| 29/11/2023 | Article B | Table B | $ 135.99 |
| 29/11/2023 | Article C | Table A | $ 13.99 |
| 29/11/2023 | Article C | Table B | $ 11.99 |
| 30/11/2023 | Article A | Table A | $ 32.99 |
| 30/11/2023 | Article A | Table B | $ 29.99 |
| 30/11/2023 | Article B | Table A | $ 132.99 |
| 30/11/2023 | Article B | Table B | $ 134.99 |
| 30/11/2023 | Article C | Table A | $ 14.99 |
| 30/11/2023 | Article C | Table B | $ 14.99 |
| 01/12/2023 | Article A | Table A | $ 29.99 |
| 01/12/2023 | Article A | Table B | $ 27.99 |
| 01/12/2023 | Article B | Table A | $ 135.99 |
| 01/12/2023 | Article B | Table B | $ 132.99 |
| 01/12/2023 | Article C | Table A | $ 17.99 |
| 01/12/2023 | Article C | Table B | $ 20.00 |
| 02/12/2023 | Article A | Table A | $ 27.99 |
| 02/12/2023 | Article A | Table B | $ 25.99 |
| 02/12/2023 | Article B | Table A | $ 137.99 |
| 02/12/2023 | Article B | Table B | $ 134.99 |
| 02/12/2023 | Article C | Table A | $ 20.99 |
| 02/12/2023 | Article C | Table B | $ 22.99 |

With this data shape you'll have more flexibility with slicers/filters etc...

Comment: Hi Sam, 
this works very well! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I have a following question. How can i create the column "Table" in your Table? I have now unpivot both tables. How can I mearch Table B to Table A and create the Table-Column? 
I tried  to add custom Column but it doesn´t work.

Comment: For each table: after you have unpivoted them, simply add a Custom Column with "Table A" or "Table B" respectively. Then in Table A query, select `Append Queries > Append Queries as New`. This will create a new query with Table A and Table B appended together. You can then right click on each Table A and Table B queries in the left pane and unselect `Enable Load` - which means those queries (tables) won't be loaded into your data model.

Comment: Hi Thank you it works now!
To be honest i have another question. I want to create a linechart and two slicers. The slicers are working, but the linechart don´t. For this example table i want a linechart with 6 lines ( Article A - Table A, Article A - Table B,...). If i´m creating a linechart it displays only 3 lines for each article (A,B,C).I was trying to change the Summarization from Value from Sum to Don´t summarize, but it doesn´t change. Do you know how i can do this, that for this example the linechart displays 6 lines?. With the slicers I will filter the table and the article.

Comment: If you want 6 lines, then create a new Custom Column (in PowerQuery or Dax) that joins Table and Article together like: `[Table] & "-" & [Article]`, then use the new column for the legend.

Comment: I don´t know how to thank you, but you helped me enormously! THANKS! Greetings from Germany!

Comment: Perhaps this could help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4egBG.png

Comment: With your help I achieved the desired result. Thank you!